# find Voltage drop and total voltage(Vs) in series circuit

Tags: voltage, current, resistors

Here is statement of question **Calculate values of Vs and voltage drops across all the resistors connected in the circuit shown below. (Note:
R is some resistor)**

[image]

**Now what i did is.There is not an resistor value on circuit and there are no different resistors on circuit like r1 r2 and so on. 2R means 2 x resistor value. So i imagined r=2ohm now i found the current using this on 2R. Current is same on circuit so used that current to find all other resistors. and than i added them**
Is there any other method to do it without supposing value of R?
Any type of help will be appreciated

Comment: YOu are overthinking this one. If the voltage across 2R = 4V what is the voltage across 1R?

Comment: 2.but If the resistance is small than voltage should drop more and more but thats not the case.

Comment: Voltage is a given fixed value so no, nothing changes voltage wise. The current on the other hand is a different matter.

Comment: Don't vandalize your posts, now they've been answered they won't be removed because they may be useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to know \$R\$.

If the voltage across \$2R = 4V\$ then the voltage across \$1R\$ MUST be \$2V\$.

Since your total resistance is \$7R\$ then \$Vs\$ must be \$7 * 2 = 14V\$

Answer (score 0):

\$ I = \frac{4V}{2R}\$

and

\$ I = \frac{V_s}{7R}\$

---

\$  \frac{V_s}{7R} = \frac{4V}{2R}\$

\$  V_s = \frac{4V \cdot 7R}{2R}\$

\$  V_s = 14V\$

You can apply the same for all resistors in the circuit.